# Python - Place a character in between a formatted string

Tags: python, string, format, center, text-alignment

Lets say I want to print out

```
Item 1           |         Item 2
A Third item     |             #4
```

Which can be done without the | by doing

```
print('%s20  %20s' % (value1,value2))
```

How would I go about placing the | character so that it is evenly justified between the two formatted values?

I suppose I could manually could the length of the formatted string without the | character and then insert the | in the middle but I am hoping for a more elegant solution!

Thank you very much for your time.

Edit: Here is a solution that I suggested would be possible

```
def PrintDoubleColumn(value1, value2):
  initial =  '%s20  %20s' % (value1,value2)
  lenOfInitial = len(initial)
  print(initial[:lenOfInitial/2] +'|' + initial[lenOfInitial/2+1:])
```

Comment: Did you try: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: Please try to use the new 'format` rather then old `%s`, Reasons? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a good source for `string format operations`: https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

for i in range(0, 5):
    print "{0:<20}|{1:>20}".format(x[i], y[i])
```

**Result:**

```
1                    |                    a
2                    |                    b
3                    |                    c
4                    |                    d
5                    |                    e
```